# TSNE plots of random data subsets are vastly different but labels are still clearly separated - what conclusions can we draw about the dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, dimensionality-reduction, tsne

I scraped a dataset of match data in a video game and labeled them according to their outcome (0 for loss, 1 for win). I wanted to see if there was actually any inherent relationship between the predictors and the outcome, so I made TSNE plots which are color-coded based on their outcome. What's strange is that the outcomes are always clearly separable, but when I plot different subsets of my dataset the shape varies wildly. Why is this happening? What does this mean about my dataset (is there or is there not a correlation between predictors and outcome)? Are there better ways to check for correlation between predictors and outcomes?

Also on an unrelated note, is it ok to feed this TSNE'd data into an SVM classifier? I tried this and the accuracy was much better than other attempts at training models (about >95% vs. 55%) which is suspiciously good, so I'm wondering if this scheme is illegal or flawed?!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

t-SNE results vary wildly with different datasets and even with different hyperparameters, so your results are not strange. However, you should ensure that you are **setting the same random seed**, because t-SNE is not deterministic; this could be the source of the vast differences of your plots.

Also, it's Ok to use the output of t-SNE as features for a classifier, as long as you ensure that the t-SNE you are applying behaves deterministically.

That said, usually [U-MAP](https://umap-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) behaves better than t-SNE, so may try with it before going all-in with t-SNE (check out [this article](https://distill.pub/2016/misread-tsne/) in such case). [Here](https://umap-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/plot_feature_extraction_classification.html) you have an example integrating U-MAP in a classification pipeline with a SVM.

Comment: I definitely did not set the seed in my code, that should be why. Thanks!